# K / Kestrel Combinator for monads?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, higher-order-functions, combinators

```
implicit class KComb[A](a: A) {
  def K(f: A => Any): A = { f(a); a }
}
```

Given this implementation of the K combinator, we can chain method calls on a value while applying side effects, without the need for temp variables.
E.g.:

```
case class Document()
case class Result()

def getDocument: Document = ???
def print(d: Document): Unit = ???
def process(d: Document): Result = ???

val result = process(getDocument.K(print))
// Or, using the thrush combinator
// val result = getDocument |> (_.K(print)) |> process
```

Now, I need to do something similar, but using the IO monad instead.

```
def getDocument: IO[Document] = ???
def print(d: Document): IO[Unit] = ???
def process(d: Document): IO[Result] = ???
```

My question is: does a combinator for this operation exist already? Is there anything in Scalaz, or maybe some other library, that does this?

I couldn't find anything, so I rolled out this variant of the `K` combinator for monads myself.
I called it `tapM` because 1) the K combinator is called `tap` in  Ruby and `unsafeTap` in Scalaz and 2) it seems Scalaz follows the pattern of appending `M` to monadic variants of well known methods (e.g. `foldLeftM`, `foldMapM`, `ifM`, `untilM`, `whileM`).

But I'd still like to know if anything of the sort exists already and I'm just reinventing the wheel.

```
implicit class KMonad[M[_]: Monad, A](ma: M[A]) {

  def tapM[B](f: A => M[B]): M[A] =
    for {
      a <- ma
      _ <- f(a)
    } yield a
}

// usage
getDocument tapM print flatMap process
```

Comment: For `IO` specifically there is a `tap` syntax method that lets you write e.g. `ma.flatMap(_.tap(IO.putStr))`.

Comment: @TravisBrown Ah, that's similar enough - the difference being that `ma` must be unwrapped before being tapped. I had to import `scalaz.syntax.effect.all._` to see that method. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Edit: My initial answer was misguided. Here's the correct one.

There's a `flatTap` method on `FlatMap` in cats and `>>!` on `BindOps` in scalaz.

```
getDocument flatTap print >>= process

getDocument >>! print >>= process
```

Edit^2: Changed `flatMap` to `>>=` to more easily show the relationship between tap and bind.